# How to display list values in tree view using SWT and MySql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swt

Please forgive me for my bad english. 
Am new for java and SWT. 
Am trying to display tree view in SWT not in jface. Getting values from database and i should display the tree view.

Tree view is like,

Template - 
    Page Number -
         Layout Number-

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem;

public class TreeEx 
{
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Tree";
    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "root123";

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        int TemplateID=0;
        int templateId =0 ;
        int  pageNumber = 0;
        int PageNumber=0;
        int layoutId = 0;
        int LayoutId=0;
List<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList();
        List a2 = new ArrayList();
        List a3 = new ArrayList();
    try
        {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

            System.out.println("Creating statement...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "SELECT templateID,PageNumber,layoutid FROM templatepage, templatelayout WHERE  templatelayout.pageid = templatepage.PageNumber";

            String sql1="SELECT count(distinct templateID )TemplateID FROM templatepage, templatelayout WHERE  templatelayout.pageid = templatepage.PageNumber";

            String sql2="SELECT count(distinct PageNumber )PageNumber FROM templatepage, templatelayout WHERE  templatelayout.pageid = templatepage.PageNumber";

            String sql3="SELECT count(distinct layoutid )LayoutId FROM templatepage, templatelayout WHERE  templatelayout.pageid = templatepage.PageNumber";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next())
            {
    templateId=rs.getInt("templateID");
                    pageNumber=rs.getInt("PageNumber");
                    layoutId=rs.getInt("layoutid");
a1.add(rs.getInt("templateID"));
                    a2.add(rs.getInt("PageNumber"));
                    a3.add(rs.getInt("layoutid"));
    System.out.print("templateID: " + templateId);
                    System.out.print(", PageNumber: " + pageNumber);
                    System.out.print(", layoutid: " + layoutId+"\n");
System.out.println(a1);
            }     
                rs.close();

                ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(sql1);
                while(rs1.next())
                {
                    TemplateID=rs1.getInt("TemplateID");
                    System.out.println("Distinct TemplateID"+TemplateID);
                }
                rs1.close();

                ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(sql2);
                while(rs2.next())
                {
                    PageNumber=rs2.getInt("PageNumber");
                    System.out.println("Distinct PageNumber"+PageNumber);
                }
                rs2.close();

                ResultSet rs3 = stmt.executeQuery(sql3);
                while(rs3.next())
                {
                    LayoutId=rs3.getInt("LayoutId");
                    System.out.println("Distinct LayoutId"+LayoutId);
                }
                rs3.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException se)
            {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    if(stmt!=null)
                        conn.close();
                }catch(SQLException se)
                {
                }
                try
                {
                    if(conn!=null)
                        conn.close();
                }
                catch(SQLException se)
                {
                    se.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Display display = new Display();

            Shell shell = new Shell(display);
            shell.setText("SWT Trees");
            shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
            shell.setSize(400, 300);

            Tree tree = new Tree(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);

            for (int i = 0; i <TemplateID; i++) 
        {
            TreeItem treeItem = new TreeItem(tree, 0);
            treeItem.setText("template "+a1);

            for (int j = 0; j <PageNumber; j++) 
            {
                TreeItem subTreeItem = new TreeItem(treeItem, SWT.NONE);
                subTreeItem.setText("pageNumber " +a2);

                for (int k = 0; k <LayoutId; k++) 
                {
                    TreeItem subSubTreeItem = new TreeItem(subTreeItem, SWT.NONE);
                    subSubTreeItem.setText("layoutid "+a3);
                    System.out.println("**********"+layoutId);
                }
            }
        }
            shell.open();
            while (!shell.isDisposed()) 
            {
                if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                    display.sleep();
            }
            display.dispose();
    }
}
```

my code is displaying like,

```
Temaple[1,1,1]
   PageNumber[1,1,1,]
      layoutid[1,2,3]
      layoutid[1,2,3]
      layoutid[1,2,3]

It should be 

Template1
    Pagenumber1
       layoutid3
       layoutid3
        layoutid3
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is in `ArrayList`, you printing whole arraylist in `subSubTreeItem.setText("layoutid "+a3)`. You probably want only one number. But from your question is not obvious, what number is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. It was very hard to figure out the problem, because there are some irrelevant code. First of all, please do not send a SQL query, try to model the problem. But. If so, call the close() like methods in the finally{} block. ;)

The problem is that you have for loops but you do not walk on it in a correct way. You looping three times, but the value is the same (the full ArrayList) you use. You get the full array via a1;
Use get() method to reach actual element or use for-each loop!

```
treeItem.setText("template " + a1.get(i));
```